# Why is there no "com." in front of my class reference in this XML

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

In my `content_main.xml` file I have a fragment, and I am reference a class from within that fragment. The tutorial I am following has me putting `com.` in front of my fully-qualified class reference but that gives me an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'multipanelfragment'". When I remove the `com.` and just leave it as it is in my code sample below it seems to work fine. I always thought you needed to `com.`, why is it working without it?

Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:context="netgenes.multipanefragment.MyActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_panel"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        class="netgenes.multipanefragment.MainPanelFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What is the full package name in which the fragment resides?

Comment: your package name is different from `netgenes.multipanefragment`. what is your package name?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the face that your `tools:context` attribute also uses the `netgenes.multipanefragment` package name, you simply didn't put a `com` in your package name when creating this project.

When you reference a class in your project in XML, the framework needs to be able to find that class in your application's classpath. To do so, it needs the full path to the class, including the Java package.

If your code is all in the package `com.myapp`, then you would reference classes like `com.myapp.MainPanelFragment`. Since your code is in the `netgenes.multipanefragment` package, you would use `netgenes.multipanefragment.MainPanelFragment`.

Comment: Ah, ok. So the `com` is more of a best practice then? I guess I just didn't add it there when creating the project.

Comment: By convention, the Java package name typically matches the application ID, and it is a best practice for both to refer to a domain that you own (e.g. `google.com` becomes `com.google`). [See here for more detail](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#package).